# how to fix LayoutInflater error in java android?

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.recipi.myapprishi.Model.RecipieModel;
import com.recipi.myapprishi.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class Recipe_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Recipe_Adapter.viewHolder> {

    ArrayList<RecipieModel> list;
    Context context;



    public Recipe_Adapter(ArrayList<RecipieModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


      //this line have error indicated by logcat
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_recyclerview , null);
      //this line have error indicated by logcat



        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        RecipieModel model = list.get(position);

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(model.getPic());
        holder.textView.setText(model.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }



    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageSwitcher imageView;
        ImageView imageview;
        TextView textView;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        imageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        }
    }
}
```

what's wrong in this code it giving me run time error like **unfortunately app has been stopped** and logcat is indicating me on bolded line

Error :

at com.recipi.myapprishi.Adapter.Recipe_Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(Recipe_Adapter.java:32)

at com.recipi.myapprishi.Adapter.Recipe_Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(Recipe_Adapter.java:16)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete stack trace, rather than just those two lines from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inflate your view in this way:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContet()).inflate(R.layout.sample_recyclerview , parent, false);
return new viewHolder(view);
}
```

Also, verify if `R.layout.sample_recyclerview` is the correct parameter.